# Use a class in my android project in a library

Tags: android, gradle

I want to reference, and use, a class in a library that resides in my Android project but when I try to include it in the library Android Studio doesn't recognize it.

I already added the dependencies in the graddla app but that only allowed me to use the library in my app, not the opposite.

How can a library reference and use a class that resides in an Android project?

Comment: Dear samia, please share some code here so can better idea about your problem.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO; I've tried to improve the grammar and clarity of your question because, when reading it as a third party, I found it difficult to understand what you were asking, even though I could understand it with some thought.  I hope my edit better explains the issue you are trying to question.  By making this edit I hope you will get more engagement with the question and receive the answer you are seeking. Don't be disheartened by my edit; this isn't an easy question to word clearly.

Comment: as @PratikDasa suggests, it would be great if you now edit your question to include (simplified) code to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve.  Although, I think the answer to your question is that you cannot do what you are trying to achieve; think about how your library would be able to reference the code in your project when deployed.  Library to app isn't a pattern that works.  But, I'm not answering properly due to my lack of extensive experience in this area with Android & Gradle.

Comment: this might help https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: i want to call a class from my project in the library but when i import the class android dont reconize it

Comment: How you are importing library, can you please tell me the steps? @samiabennour